# Equality of Integrals over a specific domain.

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $G$ and $F$ be positive functions supported on the positive quadrant of the plane, and if:
$$\int_a^\infty\int_b^\infty F(x,y)\ \mathrm{d}\mathbb{P}(x)\mathrm{d}\mathbb{P}(y)=\int_a^\infty\int_b^\infty G(x,y)\ \mathrm{d}\mathbb{P}(x)\mathrm{d}\mathbb{P}(y),\ \forall a,b\ge0$$ 
Where the probability measure is the same (i.e. same density for $X$ and $Y$).

By Lebesgue differentiation theorem $F=G$.

If instead I have $$\int_a^\infty\int_a^\infty F(x,y)\ \mathrm{d}\mathbb{P}(x)\mathrm{d}\mathbb{P}(y)=\int_a^\infty\int_a^\infty G(x,y)\ \mathrm{d}\mathbb{P}(x)\mathrm{d}\mathbb{P}(y),\ \forall a\ge0$$
Then the integral is equal over arbitrary "L" shaped subsets of the plane.
Can we conclude anything about the two functions?

The idea of Lesbegue differentiation theorem is by considering lesbegue measurable balls then finding the support of the difference is of measure zero. Can we do an analogue by considering "L" shaped subsets and finding that for a fixed $\omega\ge0 $:
$$F(\omega,y)+F(x,\omega)=G(\omega,y)+G(x,\omega),\ \forall y,x\ge0$$
Is this correct?